# What is the order of the following elements in this group?

Tags: group-theory

The group $U(10) = \left\{ 1,3,7,9\right\}$. I tried to find the order of each element and I got that the order of 1 is 0, 3 is 10, 7 is 10, and 9 is 10.  Is this true?

Comment: No. Keep in mind that the order of this group is $4$, so by Lagrange's Theorem the order of every element must be a factor of $4$.

Comment: What operation is used in the group $U(10)$?  What is $9\times 9$ when talking about ordinary arithmetic?  What is $9\times 9$ when in the context of working in $U(10)$?  What does it mean for an element $x$ in a group to have order $n$?

Answer (score 2):

No. Keep in mind that the order of this group is $4$, so by Lagrange's Theorem the order of every element must be a factor of $4$ (either $1$, $2$, or $4$). Remember that the group operation is multiplication modulo $10$, not addition modulo $10$.

So to find the order of $3$, compute $3^k \pmod {10}$ for $k = 1, 2, 4$ until you get the identity element (which is $1$, not $0$).

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this.  So the order of 3 would be 4, 9 would be 2, 7 would be 4, and 1 would be 1?  Can an element have order 0?

Comment: Correct. An order of 0 is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Let's not think too much for that one.

$1$ is the unity, so its order is $1$.

$3 \times 3 = 9$, so $3 \times 3 \times 3 = 27 = 7$ and $3 \times 3 \times 3 \times 3 = 21 = 1$, so the order of $3$ is $4$.

$7 \times 7 = 49$, $7 \times 7 \times 7 = 343 = 3$ and $7 \times 7 \times 7 \times 7 = 3 \times 7 = 21 = 1$, so the order of $7$ is $4$.

$9 \times 9 = 81 = 1$, so the order of $9$ is $2$.

This is a very pedestrian answer: the first computations (with $3$) was enough to deduce the order of all elements, but I wanted to illustrate that the definition was all you needed to get these orders.